# Making Unique List Tile item in Flutter from Builder

Tags: flutter, dart

I was wondering if it was possible to make items in List View unique in the sense that if I want to add something to the one, it only changes that particular list tile item, for example, if I added a **leading** icon from the DropDown to the one on the list, it adds that icon only to that particular list tile, and not the others (I can then add other icons from the dropdown to other list tile items).

Here's the code for it, I am not sure if this is possible since the builder is made from Bloc and an existing class **Person**, basically a template for each list item.

```
child: BlocConsumer<PersonBloc, List<Person>>(
        builder: (context, personList) {
          return ListView.separated(
            itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
              print("personList: $personList");

              Person person = personList[index];
              return ListTile(
              key: UniqueKey() //added unique key here, but it still fails
              //for example, is it possible to make this list tile unique
              //if I make change to it, it only changes the one I change, and not
              //all of them in a list at once
              //leading: DropDownButton() -> if I had a dropdown here with icon choices
              //would it be possible for that icon only to be chosen for a particular item on the list?
                  trailing: Icon(Icons.person),
                  title: Text("${person.name} ${person.age}",
                      style: TextStyle(fontSize: 30)),
                  subtitle: Text(
                    "person.name",
                    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 25),
                  ),
                  onTap: () => showDialog(context, person, index));
            },
            itemCount: personList.length,
            separatorBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) =>
                Divider(color: Colors.black),
          );
        },
        listener: (BuildContext context, personList) {},
      ),
```

more is explained in the comments.

**EDIT**
The UniqueKey() doesn't work, I tested in on my old test app I was making that works similarly with the ListTile as well, and when you change the dropdown for one, it changes automatically for all the items:

[image]

Also, here's the dropdown just so you can see if something should be changed there:

```
Widget _buildSize() {
return DropdownButton<String>(
  focusColor: Colors.white,
  value: _chosenSize,
  //elevation: 5,
  style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
  iconEnabledColor: Colors.black,
  items: <String>[
    '',
    'S',
    'M',
    'L',
    'XL',
  ].map<DropdownMenuItem<String>>((String value) {
    return DropdownMenuItem<String>(
      value: value,
      child: Text(
        value,
        style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
      ),
    );
  }).toList(),
  hint: Text(
    "Size",
    style: TextStyle(
        color: Colors.black, fontSize: 14, fontWeight: FontWeight.w500),
  ),
  onChanged: (String value) {
    setState(() {
      _chosenSize = value;
    });
  },
);
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can create an id field on existing Person class.
or you can use key, here about key
https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/foundation/Key-class.html

Edit :
sorry for my mistake, for reference link only. this is simple example of my solution

This is example of key usage

```
ListTile(
   key:UniqueKey(),
)
```

take a look this link too
https://medium.com/flutter/keys-what-are-they-good-for-13cb51742e7d

***EDIT**
The unique key is is wrong answer sorry.
first you have to create a list to contain your widget values

```
List<String> _yourWidgets = [];
```

then change your widget methods to retrieve the index

```
Widget _buildSize(int index) {
return DropdownButton<String>(
  focusColor: Colors.white,
  value: _chosenSize,
  //elevation: 5,
  style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
  iconEnabledColor: Colors.black,
  items: <String>[
    '',
    'S',
    'M',
    'L',
    'XL',
  ].map<DropdownMenuItem<String>>((String value) {
    return DropdownMenuItem<String>(
      value: _yourWidgets[index],
      child: Text(
        value,
        style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
      ),
    );
  }).toList(),
  hint: Text(
    "Size",
    style: TextStyle(
        color: Colors.black, fontSize: 14, fontWeight: FontWeight.w500),
  ),
  onChanged: (String value) {
    setState(() {
      _yourWidgets[index] = value;
    });
  },
);
```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/28049954)

Comment: @DaemonPainter hey man, i already edit my post. sorry I am new to s.o

Comment: Hmm, I think I already tried something like that. So I would just add `ListTile(
   key:UniqueKey(),
)` to the ListTile and it would work? I'll try it out, and get back to you.

Comment: For example, now if I added `leading` to list tile, and for example added some drop down, and changed the icon on it, would it only save it for that list tile?

Comment: It doesn't work, added the image how it looks now in main post.**

Comment: arbiter, oh wait. I get it now, you need to create list to hold the value of your widgets, then retrieve the value using index you get from listView

Comment: here check my post